# How to select last message by user per device

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

I've been tackling this query for quite a while without solution.

I have this table:

```
  user_id |  device | message |            timestamp 
|---------|---------|---------|----------------------|
|       1 | android |      hi | 2018-06-01T00:00:00Z |
|       1 |     ios |   hello | 2018-06-02T00:00:00Z |
|       1 | android |     hey | 2018-06-03T00:00:00Z |
|       2 | android |  asdasd | 2018-06-14T00:00:00Z |
|       3 | android |    good | 2018-06-03T00:00:00Z |
|       3 |     ios |   great | 2018-06-04T00:00:00Z |
|       3 |     ios | awesome | 2018-06-11T00:00:00Z |
|       4 |     ios |     yes | 2018-06-02T00:00:00Z |
|       4 |     ios |    yeah | 2018-06-03T00:00:00Z |
|       5 |     ios |      no | 2018-06-22T00:00:00Z |
|       5 | android |     nah | 2018-06-23T00:00:00Z |
```

How can I get the last message per device by user?

So, for user 3 I would get:

```
|       3 | android |    good | 2018-06-03T00:00:00Z |
|       3 |     ios | awesome | 2018-06-11T00:00:00Z |
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: The further I got was a message for each device, by user. But I lost my queries. @D-Shih solution's solves it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write a subquery to get `max` `timestamp` by `user_id` and `device`  and then `self join`

```
SELECT t1.user_id,t1.device,t1.message,t.timestamp
FROM (
    SELECT user_id,device,max(timestamp) timestamp 
    FROM T
    GROUP BY user_id,device
) t INNER JOIN T t1 on t.user_id = t1.user_id AND t.timestamp = t1.timestamp
WHERE t1.user_id = 3
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/24a5d5/7)

---

**RESULT**

```
| user_id |  device | message |            timestamp |
|---------|---------|---------|----------------------|
|       3 | android |    good | 2018-06-03T00:00:00Z |
|       3 |     ios | awesome | 2018-06-11T00:00:00Z |
```

Comment: The further I got was a message for each device, by user. But this solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should write this using a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.user_id = 3 and
      t.timestamp = (select max(t2.timestamp)
                     from t t2
                     where t2.user_id = t.user_id and
                           t2.device = t.device
                    );
```

For this query, you want an index on `(user_id, device, timestamp)`.

The performance should be much better than the `group by` version, because the entire table is not being aggregated.

Comment: minor typo in t2.user_id = t.user_ud

Answer (score 0):

Just order the table in desc by timestamp and group it by user_id & device.

```
select * from (
select * from Table t order by timestamp desc)a 
group by user_id, device ;
```